# comparing rows in excel VBA to calculate beta of a stock

Tags: excel, vba, finance

I have been trying to stack up the values of "NEPSE" and "PCBL" having identical date together and removing the ones which don't match up.

[image: For example, the rows that don't match are highlighted]

[image: And, this is what I want.]

Comment: Could you post the code you've tried and a little bit more info on why it's not working?

Comment: Use VLOOKUP then filter out the blanks.